# How to make transformed typography responsive on image

Tags: html, css

I have a design I'm trying to achieve with only CSS & HTML. This is a snip of a quick mockup I did in photoshop. [image: Effect I'm trying to achieve]

This is quite easy to achieve on its own but once I try to make it responsive, I'm hit by all sorts of roadblocks. By responsive I mean that the text at the side of the image retains its proportions once the image is scaled.

This is the code I have so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bob Marley Tribute</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,400i,600,600i,900,900i&display=swap');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap');

        body {
            font-family: 'Arvo', serif;            
            margin: 0;
        }

        h1, figure{
            margin: 0;
        }

        h1 {
            font-weight: 900;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        h2 {
            font-weight: 600;
        }

        .responsive {
            max-width: 100%;
            display: block;
            height: auto;
        }

        p, figcaption{
          font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
        }

        .img-div{
            display: flex;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: 0;
            position: relative;

        }

        .img-div h1{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
        }


        .img-div .lname{
            /*transform: rotate(90deg);*/
            font-size: 350%;
            background-color: aqua;
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            /*margin-right: -11.269vw;*/ 

        }

        .img-div .fname{
            /*align-self: flex-end;*/
            align-self: flex-end;
            font-size: 5vw;
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body class="main" id="main">

    <header>        
        <nav style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>

        <div class="img-div" id="img-div">
            <h1 id="title"><span class="fname">Bob</span> <span class="lname">Marley</span></h1>
            <figure>
                <img class="responsive" src="./bobmarley.jpg" alt="" />
                <figcaption id="img-caption">Bob Marley flashing his dreadlocks on stage</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>




    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: You're trying to scale the text to the *element size* and that is currently **not possible** with CSS. You will need javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container/19814948#19814948

Answer (score -1):

First, set the figure's size in `vw` (the width of the viewport) : for example `90vw`.

Then set the font-size of "MARLEY" in vw again : `10vw` if you set the figure at `90vw`.

Thus, the width of "MARLEY" plus the width of the figure will occupy the entire width of the window.

Here is my code, it seems to work fine and I get the result you want :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Bob Marley Tribute</title>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,400i,600,600i,900,900i&display=swap');
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo&display=swap');
        body {
            font-family: 'Arvo', serif;            
            margin: 0;
        }
        h1, figure{
            margin: 0;
        }
        h1 {
            font-weight: 900;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        h2 {
            font-weight: 600;
        }
        .responsive {
            max-width: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle  ;
        }
        p, figcaption{
          font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

        }
        .img-div{
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .img-div h1{
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: left;
            width: 10vw;
        }
        .img-div .lname{
            font-size: 10vw;
            background-color: aqua;
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            flex-grow: 1;
            letter-spacing: 2vw;
        }
        .img-div .fname{
            align-self: flex-end;
            font-size: 5vw;
            background-color: red;
        }
        figure {
            width: 90vw;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="main" id="main">
    <header>        
        <nav style="display: none;">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Section 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Section 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="img-div" id="img-div">
            <h1 id="title"><span class="fname">Bob</span> <span class="lname">Marley</span></h1>
            <figure>
                <img class="responsive" src="./bobmarley.png" alt="" />
                <figcaption id="img-caption">Bob Marley flashing his dreadlocks on stage</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```